# IQueryable does not return Count property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
    public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
    {
        void Add(T newEntity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        T Find(int id);
        IQueryable<T> FindAll();
        int Commit();
    }

  public class SqlRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        DbContext context;
        DbSet<T> set;
        public SqlRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.set = context.Set<T>();
        }

        public void Add(T newEntity)
        {
            this.set.Add(newEntity);
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {

        }

        public T Find(int id)
        {
            throw new Exception("todo");
        }

        public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
        {
            return this.set;
        }

        public int Commit()
        {
            return this.context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.context.Dispose();
        }
    }


    using (IRepository<Contact> e = new SqlRepository<Contact>(new AppointmentReminderDb()))
    {
        e.Add(new Contact() { Active = true });
        e.Add(new Contact() { Active = true });
        e.Commit();
        var count = await e.FindAll().Count(); // do not get Count property
    }
```

In the above line of code, I don't understand why I am not getting Count property. Instead I get CountAsynch. I really want to simply get Count property. 
My IQueryable for FindAll is correctly defined in the interface and in the class method.

Comment: What does `not getting Count property` mean?

Comment: Isn't `Count()` a method on `IQueryable<T>` as opposed to a property?

Comment: `e.FindAll().AsEnumerable().Count();`

Comment: @kcwu which would turn an operation run `select count(*)` against at database and hopefully take milliseconds into one that would do `select *` against the database and then cycle through every one of them and potentially take a very long time indeed.

Answer (score 3):

You may have forgotten to include the right namespace.

The method you're seeing in IntelliSense is named [`QueryableExtensions.CountAsync<TSource>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220196(v=vs.113).aspx) defined in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace, which returns `Task<int>` and, as such, should be awaited.

The *method* (not *property*) you're looking for is named [`Queryable.Count<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/bb468851(v=vs.100).aspx) and is defined in the `System.Linq` namespace. It returns an `int` and should not be awaited.

If the operation involves IO, which it probably does, you want to use `CountAsync`.

Comment: ... or use the `CountAsync()` method, which is the related asynchronous method that retuns a `Task<int>`.